# Given a set $A$, define relation $R$ on $\mathcal{P}(A)$ by $\{(U,V) \in \mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(A) \colon \dots \}$. Is $R$ transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Given a set $A$, define relation $R$ on $\mathcal{P}(A)$  by
$$R = \{(U,V) \in \mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(A) \colon (U \cap V \neq \emptyset) \lor (U \cup V = \emptyset)\}.$$

I want to check if $R$ is a transitive relation.

My scratch work so far:

Let $A = \{a, b, c, d, e\}$ then $\mathcal{P}(A)=\{\{\emptyset\}, \{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{d\},\{e\},\dots,\{a,b,c,d,e\}\}$.

So I know I want to prove that $URV \land VRW \Longrightarrow VRW$ for transitivity.

If I let $(U,V)=(\{a\},\{a,b\})$ then $(U \cap V) = \{a\} \neq \emptyset$, so that  $URV$,

$(V,W)=(\{a,b\},\{b\})$ then $(V \cap W) = \{b\} \neq \emptyset$, so that  $VRW$

Then $(U \cap V)\cap(V \cap W) = \emptyset$ right? Which means $URV∧VRW⟹V\not RW$.  Am I missing a key concept? Is this enough to prove it's not transitive? I know there exists subsets I can pull to show transitivity but if I show one isn't transitive, it should show the overall relation isn't transitive right?

Any feedback on this is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: yes all you need to do is find one instance in which it isn't true. To be precise notice that you only used two elements to create your counter example so you know if $A$ has 2 elements the relation won't be transitive. There is one exception is when $A$ has one element. In that case the relation is trivially and equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is fine, I’m just writing the solution because you seem to have some little mistakes in your writing (I will pointed out)

To show that a relation $R$ is transitive, we need to show that

\begin{align*}
\forall x,y,z \, ,\, xRy \wedge yRz \implies xRz. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

In this case, if we let $A = \{a,b\}$, $U = \{a\}$, $V = \{a,b\}$ and $W = \{b\}$, then we have that

\begin{align*}
U \cap V = \{a\} \neq \emptyset \implies URV \\
V \cap W = \{b\} \neq \emptyset \implies VRW
\end{align*}

Although, we have that

\begin{align*}
U \cap W = \emptyset \implies U \not R W \tag{2}
\end{align*}

Therefore, you have that $R$ is not a transitive relation. $\square$

---

At $(1)$, when in your question you write the definition of a transitive relation, you say that for all $U,V,W \subseteq A$ we have that $URV \wedge VRW \implies VRW$ which is wrong, it should be $URV \wedge VRW \implies URW$.

At $(2)$, you check the intersection $(U \cap V) \cap (V \cap W)$ which is wrong. You only need to check the intersection between $U$ and $W$ (So, the intersection $U \cap W$) in order to say something about $URW$.

---

Finally, I just want to say that your thought is right, your arguments is correct. In order to show that $R$ is not transitive you only need to work out a counter example, as you well did. Continuation of a good work.